# Increasing disk size

Tags: 18.04, fdisk

I have a disk /dev/sda1 which has 60GB volume and I need to increase it . There is another disk /dev/sdb which is 500GB and I want to raise the disk volume , is there any way to use /dev/sdb in order to increase disk /dev/sda1 volume ?

Comment: No, you can't increase the *disk* using a part of another disk. But you can easily increase the size of the filesystem on one disk by using a filesystem on another disk. This is done through a symbolic link. People use this to e.g. physically move their `home` partition to another disk. Is this what you want?

Comment: It depends on a filesystem. E.g. on `btrfs` it can be done quite easily.

Comment: @Jos , Thanks for your comment , could you please describe how can I raise the filesystem volume using another disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose /dev/sda1 is mounted as `/` but it is getting too small. Let's say you have a huge directory `/data` on that disk. You want to move that out of the way, to another partition, say `/dev/sdb1`, but still be able to access that as if it were still on your `/dev/sda1`. Suppose there is an EXT4 filesystem on `/dev/sdb1`.

1. Mount `/dev/sdb1` onto a mount point in your filesystem (I use `diskb1` here, but call it what you want):

   ```
   sudo mkdir /mnt/diskb1
   sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/diskb1
   sudo chown youruser:youruser /mnt/diskb1
   ```

The last command changes ownership of the partition to your user. Replace `youruser` with your user name.

2. Copy the `/data` directory over to the other disk. I recommend `rsync` but `cp` with the right flags would work as well.

   ```
   rsync -alz /data /mnt/diskb1/
   ```

If something goes wrong during this copy, just re-enter the same command. In fact do it twice anyway just to make sure that everything has been copied.

3. Remove the old `/data`. At this point, you have properly copied it, so there is no harm in doing this. This is the step that frees up the storage on disk /dev/sda1.

   ```
   sudo rm -r /data
   ```
4. Create a symbolic link called `/data` that points to the copy of the data over on disk b:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /mnt/diskb1/data /data
   ```

That's it. All the data that used to be available on `/data` is still there, only it's now stored on disk b. You will want to enter a line into `/etc/fstab` that causes the `data` partition to be mounted after every reboot, but there are plenty examples of that on this site.

Make sure you replace `sdb1`, `youruser` and `/data` by what is necessary on your system. Don't try this with system directories like `/bin` or `/lib`, those should remain on the root partition. And before you begin, **backup your data**.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are wanting to deal with the complexity of an additional layer, RAID, you cannot combine the space of multiple disks to form one storage volume. For "ordinary" users (i.e., no server), there is a lot of flexibility to seamlessly access storage on another location using symbolic links.

You may want to explore RAID, but do not greatly count on it to enlarge a single volume, unless you invest in additional hard drive space. A robust raid requires you to opt for data mirroring, so you need double the space.